# I would like to replace double quote from an array in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am having a simple problem with rails array.

the code is bellow:

```
 app/models/employee.rb
 s={}
 EmployeeDepartment.all.each{|employee_department|
  s[employee_department.name] = where(:employee_department_id => employee_department.id).count(:employee_department_id)
  #Employee.total_on(employee_department.id)
}
return s.to_a
```

Sample Output:

```
[["First dept", 10], ["Second dept", 12]]
```

But i need this output like bellow:

```
[['First dept', 10], ['Second dept', 12]] or [[First dept, 10], [Second dept, 12]]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain why you need this. It feels like you are actually trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: I need this to generate a pie chart. In-fact i solved it by using raw method of rails.Thanks